# file basename error ONLY with nohup

Tags: bash

I get an error when running the script (test.sh) as nohup. Interestingly, it works fine when ran as $./test.sh

Btw, the OS is X86 Solaris 10

```
$nohup ./test.sh &
./test.sh: syntax error at line 7: `file_name=$' unexpected
```

Here is the script test.sh

```
   #!/usr/local/bin/bash
   for dt in 20150806
   do
            stat_files="/storage2/Production_Stats/*"$dt"*"
            for file_path in $stat_files
            do
                    file_name=$(basename $file_path)
                    echo $file_name

            done
    done
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that.

Comment: It works on RHEL. But, I am using Solaris 10 for this. Could that have a different command format for the file_name

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had to use the deprecated back ticks `` and not the $() to make it work on Solaris 10. Thanks

Comment: That's very odd. The `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` at the top mean that it *should* be executed by `bash` (which supports `$(...)` whether it's invoked via `nohup` or not.  But it looks like `nohup ./test.sh` is invoking `/bin/sh` instead. Does `nohup bash ./test.sh` work correctly (with the `$(...)` syntax in the script)? What interactive shell are you using? If tcsh, what does `where nohup` print; if bash, what does `type -a nohup` print?